# Over-escaping html on timeline page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, timeline

Over-escaping html on timeline page?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/80046/timeline

[image]

some of html source are like this for above

```
<td class="qablock">
    &lt;span class=&quot;qacell&quot;&gt;&lt;a onclick=&quot;gotoRevision(&#39;rev-866752011-04-08-09-33&#39;)&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;qablock&quot;&gt;A&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an oversight as we convert most of our views to the razor view engine...it's been fixed for the next build.