# Overzealous HTML escaping

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, character-escaping, moderation-history

This is likely the same problem as in [Over-escaping html on timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/over-escaping-html-on-timeline-page). On the mod history page, in the list of moderator actions, some things are escaped that shouldn't be. The page source contains things like

```
&lt;span class=&quot;mod-post-actions&quot;&gt;&amp;#9830;&amp;nbsp;&lt;span
title=&quot;Some Moderator Apr 2 at 11:18&quot;&gt;Post converted to
comment&lt;/span&gt;, &lt;span title=&quot;Some Moderator Apr 2
at 11:18&quot;&gt;Post Deleted&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

which should of course be `<span class="mod-post-actions">...` and previously were.

It seems only that one class is affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. Yet another fallout of my [encoding spree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253959/115866).