# "Closed" message with Community User is over-encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed

Spotted at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253740/262755)

[image: screen shot of overencoded message]

The HTML source looks like this:

```
<h2>                    
  <b>marked</b> as duplicate by 
  <a href="/users/140890/martijn-pieters">Martijn Pieters</a>, 
  <span class="voter-history" title="This question&#39;s author approved a pending duplicate vote.">
  &lt;a href=&quot;/users/-1/community&quot;&gt;Community&lt;/a&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;mod-flair&quot; title=&quot;moderator&quot;&gt;&amp;#9830;&lt;/span&gt;</span> 
  <span dir="ltr"><span title="2015-04-17 13:09:02Z" class="relativetime">Apr 17 at 13:09</span></span>
</h2>
```

(line breaks added for readability)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed now, thanks. I'm in the process of auditing a ton of places in our code to make sure that we don't HTML-encode *too little*. It's somewhat surprising that in the process of doing that, so far I seem to have caused *double*-encoding only in a single place :)

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253778/overzealous-html-escaping) maybe related?

Comment: Very likely, yes.